# The python package 'datasets' is missing in the Text package

Tags: r-text

I am using an apptainer container (CUDA compatible) to run the function textFineTuneTask (experimental) provided by Text package v1.

```
apptainer exec <path_to_container_file> Rscript fineTune.R
INFO:    underlay of /usr/bin/nvidia-smi required more than 50 (541) bind mounts
INFO:    underlay of /usr/share/lmod/lmod required more than 50 (76) bind mounts

Attaching package: ‘purrr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:magrittr’:

    set_names


Attaching package: ‘tidyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:magrittr’:

    extract


Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

This is text (version 1.0).
Text is new and still rapidly improving.

Newer versions may have improved functions and updated defaults to reflect current understandings of the state-of-the-art.
               Please send us feedback based on your experience.

Please note that defaults has changed in the textEmbed-functions since last version; see help(textEmbed) or www.r-text.org for more details.
textrpp python option is already set, text will use: condaenv = "textrpp_condaenv"

Successfully initialized text required python packages.

Python options:
 type = "textrpp_condaenv",
 name = "textrpp_condaenv".

... some messages ...

Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) :
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.
Calls: textFineTuneTask -> <Anonymous> -> py_run_file -> py_run_file_impl
Execution halted
```

I have used the code

```
apptainer exec <path_to_the _container> Rscript -e 'reticulate::py_install(c("datasets==2.9.0"), envname="textrpp_condaenv", pip=TRUE)'
```

to solve the issue. But the error was still there.

Hope for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Recreate a container would work. It is strange that the first time installation did not have the datasets package installed.